# Gradle MavenPublication: "Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions"

Tags: maven, gradle

I want to publish a zip archive to a remote maven repository. The task `zipSources` packs a sample file into a zip archive. The publication `myPubliction` publishes to `mavenLocal` and to the remote maven repository.

The publication works - I can see the packages uploaded to the remote repository. But the build still fails with

```
> Task :publishMyPublicationPublicationToMavenRepository FAILED
Task ':publishMyPublicationPublicationToMavenRepository' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Publishing to repository 'maven' (null)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

What am I missing? How do I declare outputs for the publishing action? Or is there another cause?

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id "maven-publish"
}

group = 'com.example.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

task zipSources(type: Zip, group: "Archive", description: "Archives source in a zip file") {
    from ("src") {
        include "myfile.txt"
    }
    into "dest"
    baseName = "helloworld-demo"
    destinationDir = file("zips")
}

publishing {
    publications {
        myPublication(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = 'my-library'
            artifact zipSources
            pom {
                name = 'My Library'
                description = 'A concise description of my library'
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            mavenLocal()
        }
        maven {
            url "http://nexus.local/content/repositories/snapshots"
            credentials {
                username = 'admin'
                password = 'admin'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears there must not be a `mavenLocal()` declaration inside `repositories`, as per https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:install

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction.I needed to blindly copy and paste the `repositories {}` block from another `build.gradle` that was more recently updated.  Don't you just love microservices?!

Comment: After re-encountering the problem, I realized that I MUST have an `uploadArchives{}`. It's not enough to have a top-level `repositories {}` block